# working python xml

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization, kml

my question is the following, which is the best way of working XML (kml) with python?, especially script serializable.

thanks for your attention and answers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python and XML I routinely use `xml.etree` (see its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)). The good thing with `xml.etree` is that it's included in the Python standard library. I've heard good things about [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml) as well, which exposes an `etree` compatible api.

Comment: I just wanted to chime in that `lxml` is SUPERB and fast, and its only downside is that it is a third-party lib.

Answer (score 3):

[lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) is very fast. With large data its best choice.

Edit: But "Note that lxml does not provide any thread-safety by itself (mainly for performance reasons), so you have to take care when you use parts of the API concurrently."

Answer (score 1):

For very small and simple things, `xml.dom.minidom` is the easiest route. If you're looking for something which can handle large files with very little memory usage then you'll want to use an [xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html) parser.